# Bluetooth Command Line Tools not being recognized

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, environment-variables

When I get the following output:

*'btconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

..is this related to environmental variables? If so, I'm curious to know a bit more about environmental variables.  Why would a default installation of Windows 10 not include bluetooth in the default environment?  Wouldn't that be akin to not including netstat or ping?  If bluetooth is not specified in the current environment, does this mean that bluetooth will not be operational?

How would I add bluetooth to the current environment within the environment variables settings?

Finally, if a computer does not have bluetooth hardware installed and hardware is later installed, is the environmental variable automatically configured or does it need to be manually configured?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple - btconfig is a 3rd party tool, not part of the Windows OS, thus not included by default. It will not get installed just by adding BT HW and installing a driver - it needs to be installed manually from:

[BTConfig](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/btconfig.html)